# How to avoid storeFactory for FIX messages using QuickFix

Tags: java, cloud, fix-protocol

is it possible to avoid the creation of MessageStoreFactory while creating a quickFix session i mean when I create the socket initiator instance ?

Any solution please ?

Comment: You could either implement a NullLog or use a MemoryStore. If you are using QFJ.

Comment: Thank you John, yes it's all good with MemoryStroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the QuickFIX ports have a MemoryStoreFactory, which is an entirely-in-memory store.  Just use that.

Answer (score 0):

This is really difficult to answer well without knowing which FIX engine you are using, but generally speaking, you might well be able to configure its logging facility to not write to a file, but instead to a database, socket, or whatever you want (for example by configuring [Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) in Log4J).

If you happen to be using QuickFIX/J, it can be made to do this as documented at https://quickfixj.org/wiki/display/qfj/QuickFIXJ+Logging, since can be bound to Log4J (or many other) logging backends at deploy time.

Comment: i need to avoid storeFactory while creating a quickFix session, means i don't want to store any files/folders because i'm on read only. it's possible to avoid the logFactory but still blocked for the storeFactory